# python accurate timing of multiple sensors

Tags: python, time, sensors

I have a hardware setup (Nvidia Jetson) with multiple sensors which I read out and store for later processing. I use multiprocessing to read the sensors in separate processes. I essentially read the data and add a time to it so I can later on interpolate the data of the different  sensors so they "sync up".

To store the time I use `time.perf_counter()` because I read it is an accurate option. I don't necessarily need the time since epoch, but I do need the time of all the processes to go at the same speed as a wall clock (so real time, not cpu-time). Does this work with `perf_counter()` or do I need to use a different function?

Comment: What precision do you need?

Comment: The resolution will only be as good as the clock on the Nvidia Jetson. The most common options are `time.perf_counter` and `datetime.now`. It might be worth comparing the output to see which provides you the better results for your application.

Comment: @mkrieger1 1 millisecond or better precision would be enough